# use lookup and group different collection mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

Hello I have the following collections

```
 const TransactionSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    schedule: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: "Schedule"
    },
    uniqueCode: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    created: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },

    status: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
})


    const ScheduleSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    start: {
        type: Date,
        required: true,
    },
    end: {
        type: Date,
        required: false,
    },
    location: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        required: true,
        ref: "Location"
    },  

})
```

and I want to return how many times the schedule appear in transaction ( where the status is equal to 'Active') and group it based on its location Id and then lookup the location collection to show the name.
For example I have the following data.

transaction

```
  [
   {
      "_id":"identifier",
      "schedule":identifier1,
      "uniqueCode":"312312312312",
      "created":"Date",
      "status": 'Active'
   },
   {
      "_id":"identifier",
      "schedule":identifier1,
      "uniqueCode":"1213123123",
      "created":"Date",
      "status": "Deleted"
   }
]
```

schedule

```
[
   {
      "_id":identifier1,
      "start":"date",
      "end":"date",
      "location": id1
   },
   {
      "_id":identifier2,
      "start":"date",
      "end":"date",
      "location": id2
   }
]
```

and I want to get the following result and limit the result by 10 and sort it based on its total value:

```
[
   {
      "locationName":id1 name,
      "total":1
   },
   {
      "locationName":id2 name,
      "total":0
   }
]
```

thank you. Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit complex and long query.

1. `$lookup` - `schedule` collection joins with `transaction` collection by matching:

- `_id` (`schedule`) with `schedule` (`transaction`)
- `status` is `Active`

and return a `transactions` array.

2. `$lookup` - `schedule` collection joins with `location` collection to return `location` array.
3. `$set` - Take the first document in `location` array so this field would be a document field instead of an array. [This is needed to help further stage]
4. `$group` - Group by `location._id`. And need the fields such as `location` and `total`.
5. `$sort` - Sort by `total` DESC.
6. `$limit` - Limit to 10 documents to be returned.
7. `$project` - Decorate the output documents.

```
db.schedule.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "transaction",
      let: {
        scheduleId: "$_id"
      },
      pipeline: [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$schedule",
                    "$$scheduleId"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$status",
                    "Active"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "transactions"
    }
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "location",
      localField: "location",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "location"
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      location: {
        $first: "$location"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$location._id",
      location: {
        $first: "$location"
      },
      total: {
        $sum: {
          $size: "$transactions"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      "total": -1
    }
  },
  {
    $limit: 10
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      locationName: "$location.name",
      total: 1
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/glZgZf9VIM-)

Comment: I see so the queries is a lot more complex than I thought. Thanks a lot for your help sir.